# Java 8 Compiler Plugin : How to add super() call in a constructor?

Tags: java, code-generation, javac, java-compiler-api

I'm writing a Java compiler plugin to add a simple class named `MyClass` in some classes of my project (something like lombok does). I've managed to do it by writing the code bellow (you can find the overall code is [here](https://gist.github.com/mcherb/84324be8940737c7ad8ade03d84125f9)):

```java
TreeMaker maker = TreeMaker.instance(context);
Names symbolsTable = Names.instance(context);

//...

JCTree.JCMethodDecl constructor = maker.MethodDef(maker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC),
        symbolsTable.init,
        null,
        List.nil(), // params
        List.nil(),
        List.nil(),
        maker.Block(0, List.of(callSuper)),
        null
);

JCTree.JCClassDecl myClass = maker
        .at(((JCTree) node).pos)
        .ClassDef(maker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC | Flags.STATIC | Flags.FINAL),
                symbolsTable.fromString("MyClass"),
                List.nil(),
                maker.Ident(symbolsTable.fromString("AnotherClass")),
                List.nil(),
                List.of(constructor)
        );

((JCTree.JCClassDecl) node).defs = ((JCTree.JCClassDecl) node).defs.append(myClass);
```

I don't know how to write the `callSuper` statement to get this output :

```java
public static final MyClass extends AnotherClass {
   public MyClass () {
      super(); // I want this line
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just that line with ; behind it will do. at least, if there is a default or no-param constructor in that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `callSuper` statement is written like the following :

```java
JCTree.JCMethodInvocation superMethod = maker.Apply(List.nil(), maker.Ident(symbolsTable._super), List.nil());
JCTree.JCExpressionStatement callSuper = maker.Exec(superMethod);
```

and then use it in the constructor :

```java
JCTree.JCMethodDecl constructor = maker.MethodDef(maker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC),
        symbolsTable.init,
        null,
        List.nil(),
        List.nil(),
        List.nil(),
        maker.Block(0, List.of(callSuper)),
        null
);
```